# How can I split variables that contain both a character string and a year by pulling the year into its own variable?

Tags: r, dataframe

I would like to split a series of variables from a `df` by pulling the year from each of them and create a `df$Year` variable. The variables are currently structured like this: `df$Civilian_labor_force_2000`, `df$Employed_2000`, `df$Unemployed_2000`, and `df$Unemployment_rate_2000` iterated from 2000-2005. I would like to separate the columns into: `df$Year`, `df$Civilian_labor_force`, `df$Employed`, `df$Unemployed`, and `df$Unemployment_rate`. I can't figure out the code for `colsplit()`, and don't know if there are other ways to accomplish this.

Comment: Could you provide a sample of your data?

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 2):

An option will be to use `pivot_longer`

```
library(tidyr)
library(tibble)
pivot_longer(df, cols = everything(), names_to = c(".value", "year"), 
     names_pattern = "(.*)_(\\d{4})$")
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 10 x 3
   year  Civilian_labor_force Employed
   <chr>                <int>    <int>
 1 2000                     1        6
 2 2001                     6       11
 3 2000                     2        7
 4 2001                     7       12
 5 2000                     3        8
 6 2001                     8       13
 7 2000                     4        9
 8 2001                     9       14
 9 2000                     5       10
10 2001                    10       15
```

#### data

```
df <- tibble(Civilian_labor_force_2000 = 1:5, 
   Employed_2000 = 6:10, Civilian_labor_force_2001 = 6:10, Employed_2001 = 11:15)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can `pivot_longer` the data

```r
library(tidyr)
df <- data.frame(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8) 
names(df) <- c("Civilian_labor_force_2000",
                             "Employed_2000", 
                             "Unemployed_2000", 
                             "Unemployment_rate_2000",
                             "Civilian_labor_force_2001",
                             "Employed_2001", 
                             "Unemployed_2001", 
                             "Unemployment_rate_2001")

df_pivoted <- pivot_longer(df, everything(), names_pattern="(.*)_(....)$", names_to=c(".value", "Year"))
df_pivoted
#> # A tibble: 2 × 5
#>   Year  Civilian_labor_force Employed Unemployed Unemployment_rate
#>   <chr>                <dbl>    <dbl>      <dbl>             <dbl>
#> 1 2000                     1        2          3                 4
#> 2 2001                     5        6          7                 8
```

<sup>Created on 2021-09-05 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Oh, it is quite similar, yes. Though we made different assumptions about the form of the data (which wasn't provided in the question), so the output is different. But the method is the same.

Comment: You may need the `$` at the end `(....)$` in case there are some `_` it matches